# NestedScrollView won't work with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to learn `<CoordinatorLayout>`. I created floating labels for few `<EditText>` too, which worked well. But as my views increased I wanted to have a scrolling functionality. Enough searching about the same made it clear that traditional `<ScrollView>` doesn't work with `<CoordinatorLayout>`. We have to use something called as `<NestedScrollView>` I tried using both ScrollView and NestedScrollView but when I used them, all my views jammed up to the top part of the view as shown in the image below:

[image]

Upon execution the result remained same. My xml file is added below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/fontStyle"
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_SignupMail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editSignupEmail"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLength="64"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mail_id"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/fontStyle"
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_SignupLastName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/input_layout_SignupMail">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/editSignupLastName"
                android:hint="@string/LastName"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLength="64"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/blank"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/fontStyle"
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_SignupFirstName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/input_layout_SignupLastName">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/editSignupFirstName"
                android:hint="@string/FirstName"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLength="64"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/blank"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/fontStyle"
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_SignupPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/input_layout_SignupMail">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editSignupPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/SignPassword"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLength="64"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/fontStyle"
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_SignupConfPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/input_layout_SignupPassword">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editSignupConfPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/ConfirmPassword"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLength="64"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/confpassword"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmitSignup"
            android:text="@string/signup"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="@drawable/button_click_effect"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I remove `<NestedScrollView>` the output is just fine but without scrolling
[image]

I might've done something which triggered this behavior. It's just that I haven't been able to point it out. Been struggling with it since yesterday. Any help could be appreciated

Comment: Don't put a RelativeLayout inside the ScrollView.

Comment: But I've read somewhere, `<ScrollView>` won't work with `<CoordinatorLayout>` and `<NestedScrollView>` should be used for the same

Comment: You should use NestedScrollView when you have other scrolling views outside it (like a collapsing toolbar, which you don't have). I believe the problem is you are using a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout

Comment: @cricket_007, If I use `<Linear layout>` I cannot arrange `<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>` one below another. `<android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">` works fine if I don't use TextInputLayout. But I can't make ScrollView work with TextInputLayout

Comment: I haven't tried myself, but you should be able to use it and have them arranged vertically. Of course, you'd need to set `android:orientation="vertical"` instead, though

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly confident that ScrollView works with CoordinatorLayout or anything else in general. The only catch is that ScrollView expects itself to be the parent. If you can't have it as the parent, then use NestedScrollView.

To fix your problem, you probably need to remove the RelativeLayout and replace it with some other layout, like LinearLayout.

Comment: I tried it with Linear Layout too, but output is same as in first image

Comment: Did you set `orientation="vertical"` in the `LinearLayout`?

Comment: If your problem is solved, please consider accepting the answer so that it can be removed from the list of unanswered questions. If it is not solved yet, please provide more details about your problem.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I am using LinearLayout but it doesn't scroll smooth.